# Get a news Page full HTML externally

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I need to get the full HTML of some news Page externally using CSOM or REST or something else. I know I have to create a CSOM app or something that will have to be register as an app on SPO.

What I cannot find is how to get the full page HTML so I can present it elsewhere. Maybe a simple http Get request. Is this possible?

I know there is a rest API that we can fetch CanvasContent1, but seems messy to parse it correctly and getting all the CSS to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the page columns as HTML by using the following GET request:

```
https://{yoursite}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml
```

Comment: I think OP trying to fetch the full HTML code of news page "content" and not the column values.

Comment: This should return CanvasContent1, which is the page content.